How to select the count of tables from a database where the field="test"
I have a MariaDB database which includes several tables with same schema.
I would like to count how many tables have a specific value to a specific column, e.g. field='test'.
To explain it more clearly, the fake SQL looks like
SELECT count(tables) FROM database where field='test'
Thank you!

Hi, do you have any example that to use dynamic SQL to address my problem

Assuming some table with a field PK and value 3.
SET @field='PK';
SET @value=3;

SELECT concat('select sum(c) from (',
  group_concat(
    concat('select count(*) as c from ',
           TABLE_NAME,
           ' where ',
           @field, '=', @value)
    SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '),
  ') sub')
  INTO @expr
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @field;

We use the information_schema.COLUMNS to create a query. We create a set of UNION ALL queries, and then use an overarching SUM to aggregate the count of the other queries. Ideally like Ergest's answer should limit to the TABLE_SCHEMA too. This puts the text of the query into @expr.
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE @expr;

This is a shortcut version of PREPARE,EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE that has been available since MariaDB 10.2.
ref: https://dbfiddle.uk/Gq5NBOEx

In the folloing example I am using crm_gesti as my schema example, eid as the column name and 100 as the value to be found.
First we need all tables on your schema, which can be found by using
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'crm_gesti';


Count the values
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp WHERE eid=100;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM empNew WHERE eid=100;
......


Build the procedure
DELIMITER :)

CREATE PROCEDURE countTables(IN val VARCHAR(25), IN colName VARCHAR(255))   

BEGIN
    DECLARE tableName VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tblCount INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE tablesCursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT TABLE_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'crm_gesti';

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN tablesCursor;

    tablesLoop: LOOP
        FETCH tablesCursor INTO tableName;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE tablesLoop;
        END IF;

        SET @query = CONCAT(
            'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rowCount FROM ', tableName, 
            ' WHERE ', colName, ' = ?'
        );

        PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
        EXECUTE stmt USING val;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        -- Increment the counter if rows are found
        IF @rowCount > 0 THEN
            SET tblCount = tblCount + 1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE tablesCursor;

    SELECT tblCount AS totTables;

END:)

DELIMITER ;


Call the procedure
MariaDB [crm_gesti]> call countTables('100','eid');
+-----------+
| totTables |
+-----------+
|         2 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)


Note, If any of the tables will not have the column name eid in my case , an error will be thrown ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'eid' in 'where clause'
If you want to skip tables that do not have the column name use,
DELIMITER :)

CREATE PROCEDURE CountMatchingTablesDynamic(
    IN val VARCHAR(255),
    IN colName VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE tableName VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE matchingTableCount INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE tablesCursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT TABLE_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name';

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN tablesCursor;

    tablesLoop: LOOP
        FETCH tablesCursor INTO tableName;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE tablesLoop;
        END IF;

        SET @colExistsCheck = CONCAT(
            'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''your_database_name'' ',
            'AND TABLE_NAME = ''', tableName, ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''', val, ''''
        );
        PREPARE colCheckStmt FROM @colExistsCheck;
        EXECUTE colCheckStmt INTO @colExists;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE colCheckStmt;


        IF @colExists = 0 THEN
            ITERATE tablesLoop;
        END IF;

        -- Query to check for matching rows
        SET @query = CONCAT(
            'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rowCount FROM ', tableName, 
            ' WHERE ', val, ' = ?'
        );

        PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
        EXECUTE stmt USING colName;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        IF @rowCount > 0 THEN
            SET tblCount = tblCount + 1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE tablesCursor;

    SELECT tblCount AS totTables;
END:)

DELIMITER ;


Love the smile delimiter. Good touch.
